# Phaser - Arcade collision physics

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a simple tile game using the Phaser framework, but unfortunately I've stumbled upon a "bug" when using the Arcade collision method. I want all the tiles to perfectly stack on top of each other, but the tiles on top always go through the tiles below them.

This is the code:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(700, 700, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-demo', {
  create: create,
  update: update
});

var tiles, textureRegistry = {};

function create() {
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 500;

  tiles = game.add.group();
  tiles.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
  tiles.enableBody = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      tiles.add(game.add.sprite(i * 70, j * 70, createBlock(64, 'red')));
    }
  }
  tiles.setAll('body.collideWorldBounds', true);
  tiles.setAll('body.bounce', new Phaser.Point(0.5, 0.5));

}

function update() {
  game.physics.arcade.collide(tiles);
}

function createBlock(size, color) {
  var name = size + '_' + color;
  if (textureRegistry[name]) {
    return textureRegistry[name];
  }

  var bmd = game.add.bitmapData(size, size);
  bmd.ctx.fillStyle = color;
  bmd.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
  textureRegistry[name] = bmd;
  return bmd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/releases/download/v2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

It seems to look even worse on Chrome. It's important to note that the problem only occurs when 4x4 or more tiles are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Phaser Arcade Physics* doesn't handle multi-body contact very well, due to limitations on current version
>
> Alternatively consider using **P2 physics** instead and/or see discussions below.

---

- https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1513
- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/8191-vertical-sprite-collision-overlapfallthrough/
- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/7810-how-to-increase-rigidity-of-arcade-sprite-bodies/

  *Yes, this is a shortcoming in the separation code of Arcade Physics, which was not designed for this kind of multi-body contact. The more things are stacked on top of one another, the more weird it gets. @lewster32*